# Add new Calendar in Office 365 SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

I just created a new SharePoint site in Office 365. My experience is with WSS and MOSS 2007, so I don't know SharePoint 2013 very well. In 2007, you have a large number of list types to choose from, such as Calendar, Tasks, Links, etc. I understand that in 2013, lists are now called Apps. But the number of Apps available is very limited.

How do I create a Calendar in Office 365? How about Tasks, or Links? Do I have to add these Apps, and how do I distinguish them from 3rd Party Apps?

Update: These are the apps I can add:

```
Document Library
Picture Library
Contacts
Custom List
Asset Library
Access App
Import Spreadsheet
Site Mailbox
```

Comment: I may be very late to the party here, but check this out: http://www.benstegink.com/adding-sharepoint-2013-calendar-to-office-365-p1-public-site/

Comment: Never too late to join the party! Seriously, I answer old questions myself, because most of the people who benefit from them are those who Google for the same problem years later. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't support repeating events properly. See my answer below for using a subsite, which strangely has ALL the functionality that the main site is missing, except for theme support.

Comment: I just earned the Famous Question badge, 10,000+ views for this question. So many views, and not one up vote? Maybe there should be a badge for that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both teylyn and MLF pointed me in the right direction. I couldn't find the page "Manage my Features", to ensure Team Collaboration Lists was active (it was). Then it hit me.

When you create a site under Office 365, you get a web site:

```
 "http://{mysite}-public.sharepoint.com"
```

and three site collections, including

```
"https://{mysite}.sharepoint.com"
```

UPDATE: After researching it further, I know understand, although it ticks me off and I can't justify it, I see what Microsoft has done. With Office 365, you get a very, very crippled website (the first URL) that you can allow anonymous access to. You then get all the site collections you want (starting with the second URL) that have full functionality, but cannot be made to allow anonymous access.

So what does this mean? It means you can't have a Calendar, Tasks, or even Links on the public web site. You know, because every organization or club that wants a website has ABSOLUTELY NO REASON to need a list of events.

So, the answer is, you have to make a custom list instead of a Calendar, and try to make it mimic the out-of-the-box Calendar that SharePoint has offered since at least WSS 2.0. Gosh, Microsoft, thanks for doing all my thinking for me. I have no argument with a Blank template. I have a serious problem with not allowing me to add a simple Calendar just because it's a public-facing site. I have posted on several Microsoft forums (Good Lord, they have a lot of different forums) but no one can give me a REASON for this, other than they don't want your public site to be a collaboration site. Okay, but a calendar is not just a collaboration tool.

Thanks to those who helped me here, but I need to post this as the answer for those who have the same issue.

UPDATE: I found an improvement on my original solution. Custom Lists don't have the view cabability of Calendars, even using an Event as the Content Type.

- Use SharePoint Designer to create a subsite (you can't do it from the browser).
- Create a Calendar in your subsite.
- On the home page of your subsite, remove all other web parts and add the Calendar.
- Add links back to your parent site, and link from your parent to the subsite home page.

It's not ideal, I can't inherit themes or navigation from the parent, otherwise it would be seamless to the user. But I'm not finished yet.

Thank you, yet again, Microsoft, for tying my hands. You are not making a better product, you are simply making more skilled Houdinis.

Comment: The public web site (collection) is a specific template that includes certain features and excludes others.  You cannot turn any features on or off, so it does not have a ManageFeatures page. Instead of just changing the URL before the page, you might fare better if you use the site settings page as a starting point.

Comment: Like I said, I was thinking the two site collections were the same, but they aren't. So the out of the box lists are not available in the public site collection, but third party apps ARE? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: The public web site is a publishing site, not a team collaboration site. Therefore, it has all the elements required of a publishing site, but does not offer the team collab things like tasks and calendar.

Comment: Do you still feel that this is an answer? If not, please delete it and edit your question instead

Comment: The public site on O365 is a very limited subset of functionality, targeting anonymous users. It's rather annoying it doesn't give you the full capabilities of SP.

Comment: What is really frustrating is that you have full capability in the "Team" site collections. So, why not in the public facing web site? In 2007 you can start with a Blank or Team website and add additional lists as you want. Why not in 2013?

Comment: Updated the answer, Robert. I wanted to research a bit more before updating.

Comment: Updated the answer again, using a subsite instead.

Answer (score 6):

Try activating the **Team Collaboration Lists** web scoped feature.

Answer (score 2):

From the home page of a 365 site click the tile "Add lists, libraries and other apps", or click Site Contents > add an app.

This should take you to a page where you see "Apps you can add" and the calendar, links and tasks are among these.

I don't have any 3rd party apps on my 365 site, so I don't know if they can be distinguished.

The apps available to in "Your apps" will also depend on the template used to create the site. Not all apps are avialable in all site templates.

Also, if the site feature "Team Collaboration Lists" is not enabled, many apps (including Calendar, Tasks and Links) will not be available.

Comment: I listed the apps I can add to my post. Calendar, Links and Tasks are not among them.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check that the Team Collaboration Lists feature is enabled in the site.

Comment: See my answer. I can't even open the ManageFeatures.aspx page to see if Team Collaboration Lists is activated on my Website site collection.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for this, I created a list template to ease the process:
http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=31

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar app is very much present in SharePoint 2013. You need to Navigate to Site Contents on Quick Launch or Right hand top side click on Site Contents after that click on Add an app and you will find the calendar app which works similar to calendar in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Not in Office 365.