# Add Site Page to Quick Launch by default

Tags: 2013, navigation, quick-launch, theme

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I have one site on Office 365 (non-profit, so site is hosted for free) and one site on Apps4Rent. Both are SharePoint 2013 Foundation, although the Office 365 site is crippled for reasons I can't understand (see [Add new Calendar in Office 365 SharePoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89205/add-new-calendar-in-office-365-sharepoint-site/89232#89232) post for details).

When I add a new page in my Office 365 site to Site Pages, it automatically adds it to the navigation (the menu at the top). When I do the same in the Apps4Rent site, it doesn't. Is this a theme/look and feel thing, or what?

Update: I have determined the menu bar at the top is the Quick Launch, which of course I am familiar with from MOSS and WSS. So, under List Settings, there is the Name, Description, and Navigation, which lets me show a LIST or LIBRARY in Quick Launch. So where is the setting for showing individual PAGES in the Quick Launch? It is apparently on by default in the Office 365 site.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Site Settings > Navigation on the Apps4Rent one, I'm guessing the "Show Pages" option isn't selected for global navigation.

My suggestion would be to pull that page up for both sites side-by-side (2 different tabs, windows, whatever) and compare.

UPDATE: Looks like you're right - the "Show Pages" feature is enabled by default. It's been so long since I've used anything but enterprise, I had to look it up. Here's a couple of references that might help:

[image: Editing the Office365 Public Site navigation menu]
[image: Creating a New Page on an Office365 Public Site]
Notice in the second one that it says the page will be added to the menu. If the Apps4Rent site also a public site? If not, maybe it requires the publishing feature to be enabled for that functionality?

Comment: Good guess, but like I said, the Office 365 public site is severely crippled. Quick launch, Top link bar, Tree view, List templates, and a whole lot of other items aren't even included in the Site Settings page.

Comment: Also, this is Foundation, so the Publishing feature isn't included. I remember Show Pages from the Publishing feature when I last worked with MOSS. Now, THAT was a decent navigation feature!

Comment: The Office 365 configuration, which I really, really don't understand or like, has one public site collection and x number of internal site collections. The internal have full functionality, the one public is severely hobbled. The Apps4Rent is just what you would expect: a fully-functional site collection with all the bells and whistles (Foundation-level whistles, anyway).